# Pass Params to string in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the below Powershell line I am trying to pass the params to, however I am not having any luck.

`{request.body ? "$body = \"" :""}}{\"node\":\"$node\",\"error_msg\":\"$error_msg\",\"source\":\"$source\",\"additional_info\":\"$additional_info\"}"}`

Complete Script:

```
Param(
    [string]$node,
    [string]$error_msg,
    [string]$source,
    [string]$additional_info
)

# Eg. User name="admin", Password="admin" for this code sample.
$user = "admin"
$pass = "password"

# Build auth header
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user, $pass)))

# Set proper headers
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add('Authorization',('Basic {0}' -f $base64AuthInfo))
$headers.Add('Accept','application/json')
$headers.Add('Content-Type','application/json')

# Specify endpoint uri
$uri = "https://url.com/api/now/table/em_event"

# Specify HTTP method
$method = "post"

# Specify request body
{request.body ? "$body = \"" :""}}{\"node\":\"$node\",\"error_msg\":\"$error_msg\",\"source\":\"$source\",\"additional_info\":\"$additional_info\"}"}

# Send HTTP request
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Method $method -Uri $uri -Body $body

# Print response
$response.RawContent
```

Comment: `?` doesn't work in PS. You probably meant `$body = if ($request.body) { '{"foo": "bar"}' }`

Comment: On a side note: You can create the headers with `$headers = @{ "key1"="value1"; "key2"="value2"; ...}`

Comment: You may also want to look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722865

Comment: The line you indicated is not valid PowerShell. What is it supposed to do? A conditional assignment operation?

Comment: It's a body of a post in json format. I need to post to that URL with a raw body of json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `$body = '{"node": "' + $node + '", "error_msg": "' + $error_msg + '", "source": "' + $source + '", "additional_info": "' + $additional_info + '"}'` and it worked just fine. Thanks everyone for your help.