# Adding group members via Azure Graph API and Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

I have managed to connect to the Graph API and I'm able to pull data without any issues.   I now want to add a user to a group and I cannot for the life of me get it to work.  The MS documentation says its POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/$ref](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bid%7D/members/$ref).  I believe `$ref` is the reference to the user in the format below.   How, in Powershell, do I submit this using `Invoke-RestMethod`?

```
{
    "@odata.id":  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/a0fbxxxb7-2b3d-4df1-a0ce-3bfdb513dxxx"
}
```

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722865/making-a-powershell-post-request-if-a-body-param-starts-with for example?

Comment: If powershell is your language of choice, why not using the [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) module?

Comment: @sodawillow yeah, something like that, but I think I'm missing something.  Posting the data above as the body isn't working.

Comment: @ManuelBatsching I have managed to do everything else I needed to do using the Graph API...I'd like to understand how to do this too.

Answer (score 1):

According to my reserach, please try to update your body as

```
{
    "@odata.id":  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/a0fbxxxb7-2b3d-4df1-a0ce-3bfdb513dxxx"
}
```

For example

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer <access_token>")
$body = "{`"@odata.id`": `"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/<the user objectid>`"}"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/022af724-22e4-4838-92e9-4e561f9acc0c/members/$ref' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

Comment: Thank Jim Xu, that was just the nudge in the right dirction I needed.  I was almost there like I thought.  Here is a snippet of my working code.

Comment: $group_id = "8a1e0604-b102-48c2-a32a-c82a026b7f23"
$user_id = "a0fbxxxb7-2b3d-4df1-a0ce-3bfdb513dxxx"  

$body  = [PSCustomObject]@{"@odata.id"= "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$($user_id)"} | ConvertTo-Json

### add user to group ###
Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing -Headers $HeaderParams -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$($group_id)/`$ref" -Method Post -ContentType application/json -Body $body

Comment: $group_id = "8a1e0604-b102-48c2-a32a-c82a026b7f23"
$user_id = "a0fbxxxb7-2b3d-4df1-a0ce-3bfdb513dxxx"  

$body  = [PSCustomObject]@{"@odata.id"= "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$($user_id)"} | ConvertTo-Json

### remove user from group ###
Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing -Headers $HeaderParams -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$($group_id)/members/$($user_id)/`$ref" -Method Delete -ContentType application/json -Body $body